# How to delete older TFS builds automatically?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Or in other words: how to keep only last X TFS builds?

I didn't find such feature in TFS 2012.
Maybe someone has a script/TFS API code that accomplish such task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this by specifying the build retention policy in your [build definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716.aspx).